# iOS development/production push certificates: when and how?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

The documentation is very obscure about this so I couldn't find a real answer to these questions:

- In which exact cases should I use development certificate instead of production to send push notifications?
- How does apple detect that the app is in "development" mode? Is this something hard-coded during the compilation according to the build configuration?
- What if I create a totally custom build configuration -- let's say "TestFlight" -- which certificate should I use?
- Is it possible to use the development certificate with an adhoc release (inside a circle of beta-testers)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) The push notifications is handled by the App ID. So you can use that App ID either in a production environment and a testing one (development) ([Ref](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ProvisioningDevelopment/ProvisioningDevelopment.html)).

2) I would say based on the certificate you created (development or distribution)

3) TestFlight uses a distribution profile if I am not mistaken. From their site:

> In the Code Signing Identity drop down, select the same Distribution
>   Provisioning Profile specified in the Release configuration from step
>   5 of the “Creating the Basic Application” section, and click Next.
>   NOTE: When generating an IPA for distribution on TestFlight, you
>   should always use an Ad Hoc Distribution Provisioning Profile for both
>   the Archive and Distribute options. ([Ref](http://help.testflightapp.com/customer/portal/articles/494413-how-to-create-an-ipa-xcode-4-3-))

4) It's a distribution profile with the Ad-hoc option on (and not the Apple store one). With the distribution profile for the Ad-Hoc you can then specify which devices are eligible to be used ([Ref](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/12/23/creating-iphone-ad-hoc-distribution-builds.html))